# Enviar datos a un PHP e que una vez ejecutado no abra el PHP ni me redirecione a HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tengo un HTML  que envia datos para que una rutina que esta en PHP  los  ejecute.
Hasta ahi todo bien, pero al finalizar quiero que solo me devuelva un comenterio si todo fue ejecutado correctamente o  no.
Mi problema es que o me abre el PHP  o me hace através de un refresh de la HTML que envió los datos.
El tema es que el HTML que envio los datos esta circunscipta ( incrustada) a otra HTLM que es un main form.
Como podri hacer eso  de solo recibir el aviso.
Desde ya muchas gracias dado que soy novato en PHP y este projeto esta desarrollado en Delphi TMS Core.

Comment: haz el llamado por ajax, es decir enviando el formulario a través de fetch o axios por ejemplo, así no importa que responda el servidor, no te recarga ni te cambia de página

Comment: No respondí antes porque  estuve viendo como hacer un  envío com ajax usando o fetch  pq com axios vi que es más  complicado.
De todos modos, como  comente al ser novato en esta área no consegui enviar  ni recibir